# RLMLinkingObjects circular dependency

Tags: dependencies, realm, circular-dependency

I have an issue with circular dependency: When using the new RLMLinkingObjects for inverse relationship, I get the following error:

```
Type argument 'RCon *' does not satisfy the bound ('RLMObject *') of type parameter 'RLMObjectType'
```

I have two classes RCon and RSan. RCon has multiple reference to RSan, and RSan is referenced by multiple RCon, so it is a many-to-many relationship.
Here are the declaration samples for the classes.

First class:

```
//  RSan.h

#import <Realm/Realm.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class RCon;

@interface RSan : RLMObject
@property (readonly) RLMLinkingObjects<RCon*>* cons;
@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(RSan)
```

The other class:

```
//  RCon.h

#import <Realm/Realm.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RSan.h"

@interface RCon : RLMObject
@property RLMArray<RSan*><RSan>* sans;
@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(RCon)
```

Comment: Besides the answer given below, you could also work around this Objective-C language limitation by using generics on only one side of the relationship.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to limitation for Objective-C compiler. The generic constraints for `RLMArray` need their elements should be a subclass of `RLMObject`. But Objective-C compiler cannot recognize it from `@class` forwarded declaration.

To resolve this, I think the only way is to declare both `@interface` in the same file, then declare their properties using class extension. Like the following:

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RCon : RLMObject
@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(RCon)

@interface RSan : RLMObject
@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(RSan)

@interface RCon()
@property RLMArray<RSan*><RSan>* sans;
@end

@interface RSan()
@property (readonly) RLMLinkingObjects<RCon*>* cons;
@end
```

**NOTE: All avobe code should be in the same file.**

Comment: Thank you so much katsumi for your answer.I understand now.

Comment: Can I have above your coding in ViewController,NSObjectClass or AppDelegate Class or whatever I want ViewController?

Comment: @user3182143 Anywhere. If you'd like to declare model code to ViewController, you can. Just import the header file from the file uses the models.

Comment: I don't understand how this would work for, say, ten or more entities. What file would this go in (i.e. what would it be names and how would it relate to the class files). What would the class files look like?

Comment: @SAHM This solves a problem for the Objective-C compiler has a limitation for the forward reference. So to solve that, do not use the forward reference instead all in the single file.